# Migrate loop - SU - SF - SO

Tags: support, vote-to-close, migration

This original question was asked on superuser: [Developing online invoicing and inventory application](https://superuser.com/questions/132194/developing-online-invoicing-and-inventory-application).

It then got migrated to serverfault, primarily because the asker talked about "his clients" meaning this was an enterprise class solution.

Now it says it has been migrated to superuser, with a link to the original question on superuser, but the text says "This question is software development or programming related, and is a better fit for Stack Overflow." and can be found [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661554/developing-online-invoicing-and-inventory-application).

[circles http://img83.imageshack.us/img83/7445/googlechromescreensnapz.jpg](http://img83.imageshack.us/img83/7445/googlechromescreensnapz.jpg)

I have attached a picture with hand drawn circles for your consideration.

Comment: This question was not ideally handled, simply. It doesn't fit anywhere on the trilogy, for now. Should have been closed as off-topic and pushed the OP to ask on a site from the business section in the stack exchange list of sites. But besides, true that such situation is creating a bug. We had it with a [ping pong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39595/question-migrations-we-broke-one-closed), once, from SO to SU and back to SO.

Comment: Besides, this is duplicate of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39451/question-that-is-migrated-for-the-second-time-doesnt-have-a-migrated-to-link

Comment: It's not that it doesn't have a second link, it's that the link doesn't match the text. At first I thought it had bounced back to SU.

Comment: indeed.  the show-close-reason code just doesn't handle migrations well to begin with, and multiple migrations are particularly troublesome.  i think the "correct procedure", at the moment, is for a moderator to "clear migration history" before performing the additional migration.

Comment: Right, but the **best** solution would be to fix it.

Comment: The best solution depends on which side of the "one of us will have to code the fix" you are.

Comment: Because I don't know how the migration process works I may be over simplifying it in my mind, but if all the sites have access to the same DB, why not just insert a new entry, and tag a "migrated from / to" onto the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't fit anywhere, wasn't handled correctly (should have been "off topic") -- so it gets deleted.